# Dark Matter search, why DAMA collaboration does not publish $S_0$?

Tags: experimental-physics, dark-matter

Results from recent experiments are starting to come in, mostly in the direction of not confirming the annual modulation measuremements published by the DAMA/Libra collaboration. In the search for potentially neglected hidden systematics, it might perhaps help to have a look at a more complete picture of the collected data. From the published material available on-line, and referring to the expression for said modulated signal (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10486 at page 16)

$S_i(E)=S_0(E) + S_m(E) \ cos \  \omega (T_i-t_0)$

where I understand that $S_0$ refers to the average over that year (i.e. the average yearly background), while $S_m(E)$ represents the actual signal sought for (i.e. the amplitude of the expected sinusoidal modulation, of one year period, of significant interaction events actually detected).
Granted that I understand very well how the interesting signal for dark matter searches is $S_m(E)$, I believe that the availability of the year by year evolution of $S_0(E)$ throughout all the years that the experiment has been running would be useful for those willing to develop a more complete picture of background sources and potentially neglected systematics. Well, I could not find that anywhere ... just some comments from others who also could not find those data, but would like to gain access to them. Is there anybody with more hints on this ?

Comment: The collaboration continues to ignore community pressure tonrelease this data. Most likely because, as it has been proposed in published papers, this release would disprove their dark matter explanation.